# Derivative of function of matrices using the product rule

Tags: calculus, matrices, functions, partial-derivative

Given two real rectangular matrix $X$ and $Y$ of dimension $[n,r]$ and $[r,m]$, respectively, and a function $f(.)$, I would like to know the derivative of the expression

$C = f(X\cdot Y)\cdot f(X\cdot Y)^{T}$

with respect to $X$ and $Y$.

I'm using the product rule for matrix functions, but I got wrong matrix dimension.

Thank you for helping me.

Just to add some additional information: it's easy to calculate using the chain rule:

$\frac{\partial f(X\cdot Y)}{\partial X} = f^{'}(X\cdot Y)\frac{\partial X\cdot Y}{\partial X} = f^{'}(X\cdot Y)\cdot Y^{T}$

and

$\frac{\partial f(X\cdot Y)^{T}}{\partial X} = f^{'}(Y^{T}\cdot X^{T})^{T}\frac{\partial X\cdot Y}{\partial X} = f^{'}(Y^{T}\cdot X^{T})^{T}\cdot Y^{T}$

but I cannot use the above derivatives for the product rule in $\frac{\partial C}{\partial X}$ because of wrong matrix dimension

Comment: The last transpose applies to the product? Does that mean $f( (X \cdot Y)^T)$? The dimensions don't agree.

Comment: Is $f(XY)$ itself a square matrix?

Comment: @Kajelad It says "a scalar-valued function", hence it's hard to make sense of the formula. The transpose doesn't make sense inside or outside the function.

Comment: sorry, I made a mistake: it's not a scalar-valued function. The text is now corrected.

Comment: @leonbloy the last transpose is applied to the function.

Comment: @Kajelad $f(XY)$ is a matrix with dimension $n$ by $m$

Comment: But then you are taking the derivative of a matrix with respect to a matrix ?

Comment: @leonbloy yes! $\frac{\partial C}{\partial X}$ and $\frac{\partial C}{\partial Y}$